# Python: sort a list of lists

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list which has nested lists. These nested lists are sentences. I want to randomize the order of sentences, but the `random.shuffle()` method does not supported nested lists.

```
[['A', 'B'],['C','D'],['E','F']]
```

I only want to reorder the sentences (randomly) not the words in the sentence, how can I achieve that?

Comment: This isn't a code factory--can you please explain what you've tried?

Comment: "but the random.shuffle() method does not supported nested lists." It does. What makes you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

`shuffle` is working fine for me.

```
>>>from random import shuffle
>>>l=[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
>>>shuffle(l)
>>>l
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f']]
>>>shuffle(l)
>>>l
[['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: sry, I describe my problem wrongly...that is was I am trying to do:

import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> tg = brown.tagged_sents
>>> tg = brown.tagged_sents(simplify_tags=True)
>>> random.shuffle(tg)

Comment: I am not familiar with these modules. But what is `tg`? If it is a nested list, then irrespective of whatever the stuff before it was, it should still shuffle properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you as example

```
import random
def deep_shuffle_iter(i):
    try:
        map(shuffle_iter, random.shuffle(i))
    except TypeError: pass
```

It does shuffle of iters using recursion

e.g.

```
>>> asd = [[0,1],[2,3],[4]]
>>> shuffle_iter(asd)
>>> asd
[[4], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
```